# How to open up View Controller included in framework as static library for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-frameworks

I have a View Controller which displays many nested UIViews. I want this project which displays many views to be embedded in another project as framework. So, how can I open View Controller of my framework from another project which has included this framework for third party use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a method on your framework to return your `viewController` something like this

```
- (UIViewController*)viewControllerForWidgetType:(WidgetType)widgetType;
```

and then in the app that uses your framework use something like this

```
UIViewController* testWidgetViewController = [[TestFrameworkController sharedInstance]viewControllerForWidgetType:TestWidgetType];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:testWidgetViewController animated:YES];
```

I hope this helps you