# Load UiViewController from external framework into a storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, xib

I created a reusable **ViewController** in a external framework.

In the main app storyboard I have an other **MainViewController** with inside a container that has embeded the **ViewController** from the external framework. I have already deleted the automatic view generated inside, but it is displaying still blank and into the **viewDidLoad**() the IBOutlets were nil.
Are there other steps to be done to load it?

I tried to override the **loadview**() inside **ViewController** where I create the bundle for the **ViewController.self** and then loaded with the nib the **view** attribute of the **ViewController**:

```
    public override func loadView()
    {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: ViewController.self)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: bundle)
        self.view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    }
```

Now it is displaying,  but not corectly, I think because I load it manually and the constraints are not the same, also the IBOutlets are loaded.

I think it is a brute approach, i can't do it for every framework's viewcontroller.

Am i missing something?  It may be a compiler problem ?

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38507208/how-to-open-up-view-controller-included-in-framework-as-static-library-for-ios/38513170#38513170

Comment: Hi @Reinier Melian , scuse me but it doesn't help me too much, i wanted to reuse it automatically into every storyboard i need.